# rest api - how to send body parameters of postman in rest api call

Tags: java, rest, postman, outlook-restapi

Hi I am able to call a rest api through postman . I have added the following in body part of postman. client_id - xxxx , client_secret - *** etc.

Now i want to make rest api call through java. How do i add these body parameters to request being created from java

Comment: What have you tried so far? What client are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring, you can use the [RestTemplate](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template) Spring REST client to make a call to an external API from Java.

Example:

```
 HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
 headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
 HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(someDto, headers)
 restTemplate.postForEntity(postUrl, request, String.class);
```